# Передача интегральной переменной в функцию: по значению или по ссылке?

Tags: c++

`f(int i)` vs `f(const int& i)`

есть ли смысл в `f(const int& i)` ?

Comment: поясните пожалуйста, смысл в плане чего вас интересует?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае int нет никакого - потому что указатель может быть "длинее". Сам инт обычно 32бита, а указатель может быть от 32 до 64 бит (в зависимости от платформы и компилятора). Потестируйте, я думаю, что разницы не будет, возможно, даже второй вариант окажется медленее.

Посмотрим код по факту

```
int f1(int a) {
  return a*a;
}

int f2(const int &a) {
  return a*a;
}
```

и результат

```
f1(int):                                 # @f1(int)
    imull   %edi, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    retq

f2(int const&):                               # @f2(int const&)
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    imull   %eax, %eax
    retq
```

код очень похожий, но в первом случае компилятор смог подставить значение сразу с регистра. В втором случае он вставляет ещё загрузку с памяти. Нужно конечно смотреть в мануалы, но если бы это был старый процессор виду 286-386, то первый вариант работал бы быстрее. (да, значние в регистр нужно ещё занести, но компилятор может больше творить).

А вот если вместо int сложный объект, с сложным конструктором, выигрыш может быть очень существенный. Ведь нужно копировать объекты, освобождать память и многое другое.

В моей практике был случай, когда в функцию передавалось два аргумента, которые были просто `int a[4]`. Сделав указанную выше оптимизацию, я получил около 20 раз ускорение (да, функция была небольшой и очень часто вызывалась).

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется, разница есть. Имея `const int&`, кто угодно может сбросить `const` при помощи [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), и поменять переменную. [Пример](http://ideone.com/t51Xp2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f1(int x) { x = 5; }
void f2(const int& x) { const_cast<int&>(x) = 5; }

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    cout << "start: " << i << endl;
    f1(i);
    cout << "after f1: " << i << endl;
    f2(i);
    cout << "after f2: " << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

> start: 0
>   after f1: 0
>   after f2: 5

С передачей копии таких проблем возникнуть не может.

Comment: Вообще говоря, Ваш код содержит потенциальное UB. Нельзя изменять объект, который от`const_cast`или, если нет уверенности в том, что он не был рождён константным

Comment: @ixSci, Вы не поверите, но g++ при вызове функций с таким прототипом копирует передаваемые как аргумент константы в стек. (что это ими двигает?)

Comment: @ixSci: Потенциальное UB — да. Но если объект _на самом деле_ не константа, то никакого UB нет. С другой стороны, потенциальное UB в C++ практически везде. Разыменовал указатель, полученный как параметр — UB. Будем считать, что функции, принимающие указатель, содержат потенциальное UB?

Comment: @VladD, ну почему же. Любое *использование* невалидного указателя это UB и невалидные указатели на совести программиста. Указатель должен быть валидным, это некое предусловие, которое всегда должно быть выполнено. А вот Ваш код, который выглядит "невинным" снаружи, очень легко превращается в UB: `f2(5)`

Comment: @ixSci: В C++ граница между UB и не-UB очень тонкая. Вот `nullptr` — валидный указатель? Да. А разыменование его — UB. Или например, вот такой код: `template<typename T> (T t) { t++; }` валиден? (для T = signed int при t = MAXINT — UB.)

Comment: @VladD, примеров можно массу привести, безусловно. Это не делает код в вопросе лучше, ни на грамм. Просто само использование `const_cast` это уже триггер.

Comment: @ixSci: Если это так, использование `++` — это триггер? Использование `nullptr`? // C++ **является** небезопасным языком с «открытой» моделью доступа, поэтому на мой вкус в C++ небезопасно **всё**.

Comment: @VladD, это зависит от функции. Если есть предусловие то нет, если нет, то внутри функции должна быть проверка. с `const_cast` никакой проверки Вы сделать не можете. В остальных случаях, кроме висящего указателя, UB замечательно обходится банальными проверками

Comment: @ixSci: `const_cast` — фича языка, которая при неправильном использовании может привести к UB. Ну так и инкремент такая же фича. Поэтому я не понимаю тех, кто критикует `const_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

Передача переменной по ссылке обладает одним особым свойством: если выполнены условия, при которых ссылка привязывается к передаваемому объекту *напрямую*, то она сохраняет *адресную идентичность объекта*. Например

```
int i;

void foo(const int &ri) {
  assert(&i == &ri);
}

int main() {
  foo(i);
}
```

А уж важна ли вам такая адресная идентичность - это уже вам решать. Если не важна, то никакого смысла передавать скалярные объекты по ссылке нет.

Answer (score 1):

В объявлении `f(const int& i);`  смысла нет, так как обычно ссылки внутренне передаются как указатели на объект, а `sizeof( int * )` может превосходить по величине `sizeof( int )` и внутри кода функции для обращения к объекту могут использоваться команды косвенного обращения вместо прямого обращения к локальной переменной, коей является параметр функции.

Другое дело, если вы пишете шаблонную функцию с параметром вида `const T &`, где `T` в общем случае может быть любым типом, а не только целочисленным, то в этом имеется большой смысл, так как вызов по ссылке позволяет избежать создание временного объекта и, соответственно, вызовов конструкторов и деструкторов.
Кроме того пользовательские типы могут быть к тому же некопируемыми.:)

Answer (score 1):

Формально есть. В первом случае параметр передается по значению (с созданием копии). В случае с константной ссылкой, параметр передается собственно по ссылке, и, следовательно, не создается его копия. Фактическое различие проявляется при передаче аргументов, которые не являются POD-типами, так как исчезают затраты на копирование при использовании способа 2.