# Возврат по ссылке/значению примитивных типов

Tags: c++, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов

В [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510534/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E/510537#510537) вопросе сказано, что примитивные типы лучше передавать в функцию по значению. Насколько я понимаю, то же верно и для возврата из функции. Тогда почему операторы индексации (например, [вектора](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)) возвращают исключительно ссылки, а не специализированны под возврат по значению для фундаментальных типов? Тем более так наверняка будет использована `move` семантика.

`upd` то, что я хочу сделать:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T x;

    T& operator[](int) {return x;}
    const T& operator[](int) const {return x;}
};
template<>
struct A<int>
{
    int x;

    int& operator[](int) {return x;}
    int operator[](int) const {return x;}
};


int main()
{
    const A<int> a{};
    A<int> b{};
    //a[0] = 3;
    b[0] = 3;
    std::cout << a[0] << ' ' << b[0];
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял вопрос, то потому что пользователь хочет писать так `v[1] = 1`. Если возвращать по значению, то будет плохо.

Comment: @KoVadim для константного контейнера, естественно

Comment: в с++ нельзя перегружать функции по возвращаемому значению. Поэтому, сложно сделать так, что бы и примитивный тип возвращало, и ссылку.

Comment: @KoVadim я же и не писал перегрузить - использовать `type_traits`

Comment: @KoVadim сделать специализацию для `value_type = int, double, etc.`

Comment: Но ету специализацию нужно будет сделать только для const типов. Что то мне подсказывает, что так нельзя.

Comment: @KoVadim сделал

Comment: @KoVadim специализация нужна не для `const` типов элементов, а для `const` контейнера же

Comment: Если сделали, попробуйте сделать бенчмарки.

Comment: @KoVadim добавил код в вопрос; вы же сами показали, что разница есть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434722/235802

Comment: @anton  Вы замучаетесь специализировать свой класс для всех фундаментальных типов.:) Проблема в том, что передача по ссылке - это "дешевая" передача, то есть конструкторы не вызываются. При передаче по значению создаются новые объекты и вызываются конструкторы. Поэтому для вектора оператор индексирования объявлен таким образом, что возвращает в любом случае ссылку.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow так я спрашиваю, почему так не сделано в реализациях стандартной библиотеки?) (или сделано, но не обозначено на `cppreference`?) сам я конечно не буду ради таких микрооптимизаций что-то писать

Comment: Во во. Но эти все специализации еще нужно поддерживать одинаковыми. Проще компилятор обучить оптимизировать.

Comment: @KoVadim согласен, а можете сравнить ассемблерные выхлопы для кода в вопросе с специализацией и без?

Comment: там нечего смотреть. Умный компилятор просто выбросил классы. и сделал просто вывод 0 и тройки в стандартый вывод. Собственно, что и очевидно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если специализировать для всех фундаментальных типов каклй-нибудь стандартный контейнер, который обладает множеством различных методов, то это будет очень не эффективно.

Поэтому оператор индексирования в любом случае возвращает ссылку на объект. Передача по ссылке не является ресурсо-затратной операцией. Объекты при этом не создаются и не копируются. Более того для фундаментальных типов конструктор перемещения, как таковой, не существует. Поэтому и нет никакой необходимости специально перегружать стандартные контейнеры для фундаментальных типов, которых немало.

К тому же получится неоднозначность с определением перегруженного оператора индексации, так как встроенный оператор возвращает всегда `lvalue`.

Есть еще один нюанс. Даже если вы не собираетесь присваивать возвращаемому объекту новое значение, тем не менее у вас может быть необходимость хранить указатели на эти объекты. Например, у вас может возникнуть необходимость создать объект типа `std::reference_wrapper` допустим с помощью функции `std::cref`, который будет указывать на исходный объект в контейнере. Если не передавать ссылку на объект из контейнера, то вы не сможете воспользоваться такой возможностью.

Рассмотрите следующий пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v = { 3, 2, 4, 5, 1 };

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> rv =
    {
        std::cref(v[0]), std::cref(v[1]),
        std::cref(v[2]), std::cref(v[3]),
        std::cref(v[4])
    };

    std::sort(rv.begin(), rv.end(),
        [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.get() < b.get(); });

    for (int x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (const auto &r : rv) std::cout << r.get() << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
3 2 4 5 1
1 2 3 4 5
```

В этой программе объявлен константный вектор. Однако, так как оператор `operator []` возвращает ссылку на исходный объект, то можно связать его с объектом `std::reference_wrapper`, и тем самым представлять элементы исходного вектора упорядочными по различным критериям.

То есть неважно, является ли объект константным или нет, тем не менее нередко необходимо получить на него ссылку, чтобы отслеживать его состояние. Константные объекты могут помимо прочего быть еще и `volatile` объектами или иметь члены данных с модификатором `mutable`.

Если же возвращать объект по значению из оператора, то связь с исходным объектом будет утеряна, и вы будете иметь дело с копией.

Comment: А нельзя ли при помощи TMP провести _лишь одну_ «специализацию»? По идее, код для всех примитивных типов будет один и тот же? (Это к первому аргументу об эффективности, второй аргумент о том, что индексирование возвращает ссылку, понятен.)

Comment: @VladD Это только будет засорять язык и стандарт языка ради непонятных и сомнительных преимуществ.

Comment: @VladD is_same <int> and is_same<double> etc

Comment: @VladfromMoscow засорять исходники?) там итак кромешная мгла, думаю есть оптимизации и похлеще, если это действительно является оптимизацией

Comment: можете про третий пункт подробнее расписать? когда нам нужны константые указатели на примитивные типы взамен их самих?

Comment: @anton Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну то что можно так сделать понятно, но что может `rv` такого, что не может `v`? в целом `rv` работает потенциально медленнее

Comment: то есть суть в том, что у константной ссылки нет функциональной пользы, только польза в отсутствии аллокации, которая в случае с фундаментальными типами не даёт выиграша в скорости, а скорее наоборот

Comment: @anton Причем здесь медленнее или не медленнее? Вы не можете сортировать константный контейнер. Без получения ссылок на исходные объекты контейнера, вы не сможете представлять элементы контейнера упорядоченными. Это и позволяет сделать оператор индексирования, который возвращает ссылку, а потому на исходный объект можно получить указатель. Имейте в виду, что тем самым облегчается написание шаблонного кода, так как в нем достаточно использовать этот оператор для объектов любого типа и любого контейнера, предоставляющего оператор индексирования.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow согласитесь, сортировать константый контейнер уже хак

Comment: а вот насчёт `mutable` и `volatile` вы правы, пожалуй

Comment: @anton Вы, похоже, не поняли пример, который присутствует в моем ответе. Исходный вектор не сортируется. Тем не менее к нему можно предоставить доступ как к отсортированному вектору.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow да, точно, возможно, это может понадобиться, согласен

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, разве в таком случае не проще скопировать вектор? Если брать ссылки (читай: указатели) на элементы, то получаем лишнюю память. А так - скопировал и сортируй на здоровье, типы всё равно фундаментальные

Comment: @int3 А копируя вектор целиком не будет задействована лишняя память? Причем имейте в виду, для вас вектор может быть константным, например, передан в функцию по константной ссылке, а на самом деле вектор не константный. Тогда вам постоянно придется делать копию вектора.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, это то, что требуется.

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    using ConstIndexRetType = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, const T&>::type;
    T x;

    T& operator[](int) { return x; }
    ConstIndexRetType operator[](int) const { return x; }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
    struct C {};

    const A<int> a;
    const A<C> b;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a[1]), int>::value, "?");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(b[1]), const C&>::value, "?");
}
```

Comment: да, нечто подобное, но, опять же, я спрашиваю, почему это не реализовано в стандартной библиотеке? действительно ли это даёт пользу?

Comment: @anton, не берусь отвечать за разработчиков STL, но предполагаю: помимо стандартных типов, могут быть всякие struct Q { char a[2]; }, которые тоже занимают пару байт. По идее, есть смысл их передавать по значению. Тогда нужно фильтровать по размеру типа? Нет, ибо может быть нетривиальный конструктор копирования (копирование данных, расположенных по указателю, например)

Answer (score 1):

А давайте глянем на практике... Так сказать, найдите три отличия: https://godbolt.org/g/s95gJt

Вот это

```
void f(const A<int>& a, A<int>& b)
{
    std::cout << a[0];
    std::cout << b[0];
}
```

компилируется в

```
    push    rbx
    mov     rbx, rsi
    mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
    mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbx]
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
    pop     rbx
    jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
```

Как видите, разницы никакой.

Comment: Это код без оптимизации. Если чуточку добавить  ее, то будет вообще хорошо:) я писал об этом выше - компилятор просто подставит константы ( в Вашем случае  - просто нули).

Comment: @KoVadim Я убрал этот кусок, чтоб не смущать незрелые умы :) - можете посмотреть правки. Или по ссылке - там это тоже показано.